# Make Column Data as Column Header whole year in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

Hi im working on a query on oracle with the sample data like this
[[image: Samle data1]

expected Result but the whole year
will also display other month even if there's no data for that month
[image: Expected Out put]

i've search the internet for this but cant find any related to my problem

here's what i have tried but i think im in a wrong way

```
select * from(
select fd.empid,fd.employeename,to_char(fd.payrolldate,'Month') as Month,fd.for_deduction15th,d.DEDUCTED15TH,fd.for_deduction30th,d.DEDUCTED30TH from 
VW_MTS_FOR_DEDUCTION FD
full outer join VW_MTS_DEDUCTED D
on FD.EMPID = D.EMPID
and FD.PAYROLLDATE = D.PAYROLLDATE
)
pivot(max(Month) for Month in ('March' ,'April','February' ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `PIVOT` was close, but you need to use the "deduction" columns in your pivot.  Below is a sample query with assumed data since the actual data in the tables was not shared.

```sql
--Setup of sample data
WITH
    VW_MTS_FOR_DEDUCTION (empid,
                          employeename,
                          payrolldate,
                          for_deduction15th,
                          for_deduction30th)
    AS
        (SELECT 233, 'HERNANDEZ, CECILIA ALVANO', DATE '2021-3-1', NULL, 2 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 233, 'HERNANDEZ, CECILIA ALVANO', DATE '2021-4-1', NULL, 1778 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 233, 'HERNANDEZ, CECILIA ALVANO', DATE '2021-4-1', 1, NULL FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 40079, 'ALLASAS, DERRICK AMANTE', DATE '2021-4-1', NULL, 1 FROM DUAL),
    VW_MTS_DEDUCTED (empid,
                     payrolldate,
                     DEDUCTED15TH,
                     DEDUCTED30TH)
    AS
        (SELECT 233, DATE '2021-3-1', NULL, 1 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 233, DATE '2021-4-1', NULL, 1777 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 233, DATE '2021-4-1', 1, NULL FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 40079, DATE '2021-4-1', NULL, 1 FROM DUAL)
  --Actual query
  SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT fd.empid,
                 fd.employeename,
                 TRIM (TO_CHAR (fd.payrolldate, 'Month'))     AS mon,
                 fd.for_deduction15th,
                 d.DEDUCTED15TH,
                 fd.for_deduction30th,
                 d.DEDUCTED30TH                               as
            FROM VW_MTS_FOR_DEDUCTION FD
                 LEFT JOIN VW_MTS_DEDUCTED D ON FD.EMPID = D.EMPID AND FD.PAYROLLDATE = D.PAYROLLDATE)
         PIVOT (MAX (for_deduction15th) AS for_deduction15th,
                MAX (DEDUCTED15TH) AS DEDUCTED15TH,
                MAX (for_deduction30th) AS for_deduction30th,
                MAX (DEDUCTED30TH) AS DEDUCTED30TH
               FOR mon
               IN ('March' AS march, 'April' AS april))
ORDER BY empid;
```

```
   EMPID                 EMPLOYEENAME    MARCH_FOR_DEDUCTION15TH    MARCH_DEDUCTED15TH    MARCH_FOR_DEDUCTION30TH    MARCH_DEDUCTED30TH    APRIL_FOR_DEDUCTION15TH    APRIL_DEDUCTED15TH    APRIL_FOR_DEDUCTION30TH    APRIL_DEDUCTED30TH
________ ____________________________ __________________________ _____________________ __________________________ _____________________ __________________________ _____________________ __________________________ _____________________
     233 HERNANDEZ, CECILIA ALVANO                                                                              2                     1                          1                     1                       1778                  1777
   40079 ALLASAS, DERRICK AMANTE                                                                                                                                                                                  1                     1
```

Comment: hi how can i display zero in other month if there's no data on the table for that month?
i want to display all month

Comment: Just use `nvl(..., 0)`